# Sikuli freezes on startup

Tags: java, windows, sikuli

everyone. I'm not so intimate with Java and Sikuli, more like an enthusiast. I've installed Sikuli in 3 different PCs and worked fine in all of them, but for a forth one I had a strange behavior, and couldn't find any log or information that could help me to check the error. The batch runs and then the loading screen freezes, and nothing happens, no matter how much time I gave to it. All PCs have the same Java version.

[image]

Could someone give me a hand? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the same version of Java on the other PCs? 
Can you try using Java 7?

I noticed you run the "runIDE.cmd". Is this the default cmd to run for the IDE to launch? I know in Sikuli 1.0.0 there was a sikuli-ide.cmd.

Good luck.

Comment: Hello, matteo. Thanks for your answer. All PCs are using the same Java version and I can't change this, since there are other applications that run in these PCs that depends on the current installed version. I wasn't able to install it from scratch due to the company's policy, so I'm not sure if the batch is the same. Basically this batch sets Sikuli parameters, check the java version and execute the jar file. I can send you the CMD if this info is not enough to help.

Answer (score 0):

I also have Sikuli installed on my work PC. 
 
There I have Sikuli 1.0.1 as you do. 
 
But I think I use the "runIDE.cmd" to start Sikuli.

Also you need Java and JDK to run it.

Edit: 
This is my log from the startup:

```
+++ running this Java
java version "1.7.0"
Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
java Hotspot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed code)
+++ trying to start Sikuli IDE 
+++ using: -Xms64M -Xmx512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsikuli.FromCommandLine 
-jar C:\<path>\sikuli-ide.jar
```

I did google on old Java version and Sikuli. 
And the I found this page: [Link](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/236126)

Maybe you can try Raiman's first post. 
Seems to have helped somebody with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tenzin. The PC has Java 1.6.0.12 already installed. I also use runIDE.cmd batch to start Sikuli, as you can check in the top bar of the screenshot I provided, Any ideas of how can I verify what's wrong? Any Java log or something? Thanks.

Comment: I will have to look tommorow on my work. I use it very active lately becasue I am working on some code from it.

Comment: Adjusted my post. 
Maybe that will help you.

Comment: Hello, Tenzin. I've tested it but the same error still occurs.

Comment: Try making a debug file. Open a command prompt and start Sikuli from there with runIDE.cmd -d3 
Maybe that will tell you more about where it is stuk.

Comment: Hello, again. Thanks for the reply, but it didn't help again =/. All information that debug gives is exactly the same between a PC that works and the one that crashes. I'm hopeless!